# Table thead equal to tbody using jquery. How to do it?

Tags: jquery, html-table, responsive

I have table something like this:

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
}
thead, tbody {
  display: block;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid #454545;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">test1</th>
      <th colspan="2">test2</th>
      <th rowspan="2">test3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>test4</th>
      <th>test5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**I want to do:**

- td - 1 and 2 equal to th - test1
- td - 3 equal to th - test4
- td - 4 equal to th - test5
- td - 5 and 6 equal to th - test3

I'm looking for jQuery solution but maybe it is not necessary.

**More info:**
tbody and thead must be with display:block, because tbody will be in future with overflow-y scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can equalize width cols only use html attributes.

```html
<p>Bad value for colspan , minor than cols numbers </p> 
<table border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">1 col</td>
       <td colspan="5">5 col</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1 col</td>
       <td>2 col</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>Correct value</p> 
 <table border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">1 col</td>
       <td colspan="5">5 col</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1 col</td>
       <td>2 col</td>
       <td>3 col</td>
       <td>4 col</td>
       <td>5 col</td>
       <td>6 col</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>Table inside table, width auto</p> 
 <table border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">1 col</td>
       <td colspan="5">
         <table border="1"> 
             <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"> 5 cols Title header</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td> hcol1 </td>
                <td> hcol2 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1 col</td>
       <td>2 col</td>
       <td>3 col</td>
       <td>4 col</td>
       <td>5 col</td>
       <td>6 col</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>Table inside table, width 100% </p> 
 <table border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">1 col</td>
       <td colspan="5">
         <table border="1" style="width:100%"> 
             <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"> 5 cols Title header</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td> hcol1 </td>
                <td> hcol2 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>1 col</td>
       <td>2 col</td>
       <td>3 col</td>
       <td>4 col</td>
       <td>5 col</td>
       <td>6 col</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

But if you want make it with Jquery you need set some attribute or var for know which col need more colspan size.  Write less do more  , here is no posible.

It looks like you want to make a grid system with tables, bad idea. 
If so, I advise you to use for example Bootstrap.

If no, you can set attribute to each td tag for example "group-td" and other attribute with the references th header tag. Then select tbody td and make groups of elements by group-td value, get the reference width and divide width or height. But you always will have got problems with paddings , and borders.

Comment: Thats why im looking for jquery solution. I dont want to use equalize width cols. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: @Nienormalny_: Can you explain why you don't want to use `colspan`? Your table doesn't make much sense without it.

Comment: No , i want use colspan and rowspan , is the best option. But if you want make with Jquery you need configurate a lot of things Jquery is no magic. And the end you write more.
The best way is write colspan and rowspan or multiples tables

Comment: It has some `colspans` and thats make sens when this table has 5 more th and 10 more td. Im looking to do this responsive. When i change width of browser then td is not with the same width and is not equal to th.

Comment: try creating tables inside tables with width 100%

Comment: ok i will try it if its help i will give check for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do it on first 4 th and thats help nothing. I need to do this with jquery. its too much th and too much td.
So thats looks like`<tr>` x 9 th - this is first tr; `<tr>` x 9 th - this is second tr; and 18 td

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Just use HTML colspans in first header row:

```
<tr>
      <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">test1</th>
      <th colspan="2">test2</th>
      <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">test3</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I Have provided another answer with JQuery, please try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are so particular about Using JQuery, try following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = $(".table thead tr th");
$(x[0]).attr("colspan","2");
$(x[2]).attr("colspan","2")
});
```

Comment: It essentially does the same thing, but during run time instead of during designing HTML.